# regular expression doens't work

Tags: regex, linux, terminal

Hi i'm new to linux and regex and i'm trying to delete a phonenumber, ip adress and email from a txt file. I'm using sed to get some information out of a txt file. this is the commmand I use to get that information. somehow it doens't work please help.

```
sed '/(^\d{2,4}\\\d{6,8}$)|(^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-ZA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})$)|(\d{4}\.\d{4}\.\d{4})/' test.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regex for Phone

```
\(?\b[0-9]{3}\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0LPnY6FC21YVtPES)

**Matches:**

```
3334445555, 333.444.5555, 333-444-5555, 333 444 5555, (333) 444 5555 and all combinations thereof.
```

### Regex for IPAddress

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3bLQSyTh_VnNyxHC)

### Regex for Email

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2i7iIrSYXFBplVfx)